# adding tooltip on body tag not showing up d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating svg chart and trying to add a tooltip, I've tried all different methods and it seems to be not showing, I can see information inside div tag changing and from "display": "none" it changes to "display":"block" however not showing up on the chart. Thanks for the help!

This is my js:

```
var innerChartCircle = scatterChartGroup.selectAll("circle")
      .data(fulldata)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => xScale(d[CurrentXLabel]))
      .attr("cy", d => yScale(d[CurrentYLabel]))
      .attr("r", 10)
      .attr("fill", "green")
      .attr("opacity", 0.4)
      .attr("stroke", "yellow")
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").classed("tooltip",true);

    innerChartCircle.on("mouseover", function(d,i){
      tooltip.style("display", "block");
      tooltip.html("Hello World")
        .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
        .style("top", d3.event.pageY + "px")
    }).on("mouseout", function(){
      tooltip.style("display", "none")
    })
```

and Css:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
}
```

I really cannot find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It seems to work fine - https://jsfiddle.net/qgo1n208/ . Can you check the console for errors (if any)?

Comment: Nope, not outputting anything on console...

Comment: Okay so can you update your post with the missing variables - fulldata, xScale, yScale? In short, can you post a working example/snippet?